# Fill the List of Expressions with the class properties based on list of string

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, c#-4.0, expression

There is a class Employee, defined below:

```cs
class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

and I need to fill in the list of expressions, something like below:

```cs
var expressions = new List<Expression<Func<Employee, object>>>()
{
    e => e.Id,
    e => e.Name
}
```

but that should be based on another string which is

```cs
var fields = new List<string>() { "Id", "Name" };
```

So the idea is to fill the expressions list with those fields which are there in the fields string list. Therefore we will search those exact field names in the Employee class and based on that get the property and fill the expressions list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure out how to do this for one property name first.

```
Expression<Func<Employee, object>> GetExpression(string propertyName) {
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee));
    var propertyInfo = typeof(Employee).GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (propertyInfo == null) {
        throw new Exception("No such property!");
    }
    var memberAccess = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, object>>(
        propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType ?
            Expression.Convert(memberAccess, typeof(object)) :
            memberAccess, 
        parameter);
}
```

Note that you will need an `Expression.Convert` if the type of the property is a value type. This is to box the value into an `object`.

Then you can just `Select` the list of names:

```
List<Expression<Func<Employee, object>>> GetExpressions(List<string> propertyNames) =>
    propertyNames.Select(n => GetExpression(n)).ToList();
```